# Why is the word 'skilful' not spelled 'skillfull'

Tags: word-formation

Skilfull seems the sensible spelling to me as this compound word refers to sb or sth that is full of skill. So why isn't it spelled as the word it comes from?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61092/dropping-l-in-compound-adjectives-is-it-skillful-or-skilful) from the sister EL & U site.

Comment: You must realise that there is little or no logic to English spelling.  Also the conventional US spelling is "skillful" and this spelling is increasing common in British English. See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61092/dropping-l-in-compound-adjectives-is-it-skillful-or-skilful